# Two text inputs values are updated, one is still blank

Tags: jquery, html, geolocation

In my view, I have two text input fields. Each embedded inside their paragraph.

```
<p><input id="filterNearbyLatitude" name="filterNearbyLatitude" type="text" class="form-control numeric" placeholder="Latitude"/></p>
<p><input id="filterNearbyLongitude" name="filterNearbyLongitude" type="text" class="form-control numeric" placeholder="Longitude"/></p>
```

When I attempt to ascertain the coordinates of the user, and if the user agrees, the coordinates are gathered:

```
$(function () {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition, positionError);

    function showPosition(position) {
        var coordinates = position.coords;
        derivedLatitude = coordinates.latitude;
        derivedLongitude = coordinates.longitude;
        $('#filterNearbyLatitude').val(derivedLatitude);
        $('#filterNearbyLongtitude').val(derivedLongitude);
        console.log('Derived Coordinates: Lat:' + derivedLatitude + ' Lng:' + derivedLongitude);
    }

    function positionError(position) {
        derivedLatitude = 0;
        derivedLongitude = 0;
        $('#filterNearbyLatitude').val();
        $('#filterNearbyLongtitude').val();
        console.log('Derived Coordinates Failed');
    }
});
```

Everything appears to work as I thing it should, the user is prompted to allow their location to be determined, the variables derivedLatitude and derivedLongitude are set, and a console message is written.

```
Derived Coordinates: Lat:39.747606140632754 Lng:-84.1504838931303
```

The problem is when those two variables (derivedLatitude and derivedLongitude) are set as values in the two text inputs. The latitude gets set, but the longitude is always blank.

I can't find out why only one field is getting updated. A second pair of eyes would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: `filterNearbyLongtitude` typo, extra t

Answer (score 0):

@Taplar was able to spot the typo that was overlooking for hours.

Comment: When in doubt, `console.log($(selector).length)` can let you know if your selector is finding what it's looking for at the point in time that you are trying to use it.  Followed by trying to figure out why it's 0, :)

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong id. Please update to this line of code.

```
$('#filterNearbyLongitude').val(derivedLongitude);

$('#filterNearbyLongitude').val();
```